# Move marker between multiple locations with animation on Google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I want to move a car icon between two location coordinates and i want to change the duration(speed) of that car icon by slider.

i tried CATransaction to animate the marker.Its animating fine but i am not able to change the duration(speed) at real time by slider.

Here is my code for animating the marker.

```swift
func moveTo(point: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        if let marker = arrMapList[0] as? GMSMarker {
         let angle = getAngle(fromLoaction: marker.position, toLocation: points[currentIndex])
        marker.rotation = CLLocationDegrees(angle * (180.0 / .pi))
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(5)
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                if let nextPoint = self.getNextPoint(currentIndex: self.currentIndex) {
                    self.moveTo(point: nextPoint)
                }
            }
            marker.position = point
            CATransaction.commit()
    }
    }
```

I tried to change duration as follow but its not working.

```swift
@IBAction func SliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(CFTimeInterval(sender.value))
    }
```

Marker(car) icon should be move between two coordinate and if user change the value of speed by slider moving left or right, Animation duration should be effected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the duration of an in-flight animation.

You should be able to change the layer's speed parameter to speed it up.

Speed = 1.0 is normal speed. Speed 2.0 would be twice as fast (half the duration). A speed of 0.5 would be half-speed.

You'd use code like

```
marker.layer.speed = 2.0
```

(You'll need to refactor to set the speed from the slider. Try a range from 0.5 to 1.5.)

Comment: Thanks for answering Duncan C. But there is a problem when i move slider it moves maker to the destination point quickly not by speed i am setting from slider.